# How do I add a message that the filtered parameter does not exist

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the following function to filter through worksheets.  Works fine, but what I don't have a way inform the user if the parameter entered does not exist. I am looking for some assistance, on this issue.  Here is my function:

```
    Public Function filterSheets(Sheets As Worksheet, searchRange As String, operator As String, filterString As String)

'This function is used to filter sheets by deleting any rows
'that do not contain the value stated in variable filterString


Dim lngLastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Sheets

        lngLastRow = GETLASTROW(.Cells)

        If lngLastRow > 1 Then
            'we don't want to delete our header row
            With .Range(searchRange & lngLastRow)

                    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=operator & filterString


                    .EntireRow.delete
            End With
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Here is the procedure that uses my function:

```
Sub filterSheets

For Each ws In Sheets(Array("Return to Work Report", "New Leaves Report"))

filterRange = ("H2:H")
compOperator = "<>"
filterString = locationCode

    Call filterSheets(ws, filterRange, compOperator, filterString)

       Next ws

End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a check of existing rows, since you're only deleting items.

```
Dim lr as long, lra as long
lr = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row

    'do all of your other code

lra = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
If lr=lra then msgbox("Your criteria can't be filtered.")
```